# CentOS 6.4 Missing Network Route on boot up after minimal install

Tags: linux-networking, centos6

I am testing a server configuration using CentOS 6.4.  I do a minimal install and in the process of installing choose eth0 to be enabled at boot and enter a static IP address and gateway.

When I boot the system up I can ping the router at 192.168.1.1.  I can not ping google.com nor yahoo.com.  I can not ping any external IP addresses outside of my local network.  I can SSH from to this system from a system on the same local network (subnet)

If I run:

```
route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

everything works great.  Until I restart that is. Then the same thing happens.  I must run that command first.

I have tried various forms of editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` as well as `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`

I have tried adding a GATEWAY=192.168.1.1 line to /etc/sysconfig/network

I've tried playing with NetworkManger and installing through yum, and that seemed to make things worse.  All without luck.

So at this point I have just done a complete reinstall from the DVD ISO to confirm I didn't imagine it all with all of the configuration changes I've made, and I still have the same issue.

Can someone please tell me what the best way of handling this is?

My info is:

```
IP address of machine: 192.168.1.110
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway IP: 192.168.1.1

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="0e8f1aa3-a071-4de1-90d8-561204faf2f3"
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
HWADDR=00:22:4D:A0:0A:CF
IPADDR=192.168.1.110
PREFIX=24
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

Before the install process I ran the media check on the DVD I burned it onto.  Before that I verified the MD5sum of the ISO file as well.

Comment: Add the content of the ifcfg-eth0 file to your post please.

Comment: Also, can you verify if you have indeed checked the ISO to ensure checksums match? Just to rule out any issues with the install medium (not that it sounds like there should be any, but at least we can rule it out of the equation)

Comment: can you show the output of `route -n` before you run the route command

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I have answered all your questions in the post itself now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way the minimal install works.

Why it's not sticking is another thing (MadHatter answered as I was finishing), add GATEWAY=192.168.1.1 to the ifcfg-eth0 file.

http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOSMinimalCD6.4

> If you did not configure the network during installation ( see CentOS-6 FAQ#2) then:
>
> make sure that the interface is activated at boot time ( set the
>   ONBOOT parameter in the interface configuration file to "yes"). if you
>   are not using DHCP, you will have to manually configure your network
>   interfaces because NetworkManager is not included. Documentation is
>   here. Do not forget about DNS and **default route**.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, and either do `service network restart`, or reboot.  And make really sure NetworkManager's disabled by changing `NM_CONTROLLED="yes"` to `NM_CONTROLLED="no"` in the same file, that thing's a vile horror for servers.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the NM_CONTROLLED flag as well.  I changed this too.